# Iphone: How can I make a grouped table NOT "move" when entering editing mode?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, editing

I have a grouped tableview with two sections, and I want the cells (in editing mode) to look like the "add stocks view" in the stocks application from Apple. I want the delete button to be positioned directly over the cells, and not to the left of the cells.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try implementing `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` in table delegate and return NO from it.